# Do they require Schengen transit visa at Istanbul airport to give me my boarding pass?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, iranian-citizens

I want to travel from Istanbul to Canada using Turkish Airlines. I have an Iranian passport and student visa for Canada. From what I've heard, I don't need a transit visa for my layovers but it seems Turkish Airlines might check for one. Will they?

Comment: Airlines use a database called Timatic to check what visas you need. So the answer to this question should be that they will only check for a visa if you actually need that visa, and you can check that using the information in the question I linked.

Comment: Neither Turkey nor Canada are in the Schengen area. How does Schengen become relevant for the question at all? Is there a layover in a Schengen airport _between_ Turkey and Canada that the question doesn't mention? (I don't think Turkish Airlines would have any direct flights between Schengen and Canada).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: The tags (original to the OP) mention Schengen, though the text doesn’t.  It might be a code-share itinerary with the first leg operated by Turkish and the second leg by someone else.